# voxel_grid visualization in rviz

Tags: navigation, rviz, costmap-2d, voxel-grid, costmap-2d-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I'm working with the navigation stacks, I made a costmap_2d/VoxelGrid with all my sensor data in it and I use this to navigate through the environment. I can see the laser and all my sensor in rviz but it would be nice to just visualize my costamp (VoxelGrid data type) instead of all the sensor separately. Is it possible to visualize the costamp_2d in rviz?? of is there any plug-in to convert my costmap in a data type that rviz can plot??

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12975/voxel_grid-visualization-in-rviz/) by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on ROS Answers with karma: 370 on 2012-02-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not used it lately, but the [`costmap_2d_cloud` utility](https://code.ros.org/gf/project/ros-pkg/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=%2Fstacks%2Fnavigation%2Ftrunk%2Fcostmap_2d%2Fsrc%2Fcostmap_2d_cloud.cpp&view=markup&revision=23884) included in the `costmap_2d` package can publish your grid contents as `sensor_msgs::PointCloud`.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For reference, put it alongside rviz in a launcher like this:

```
<launch>
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find gopher)/rviz/view_navigation.rviz">
    <remap from="initialpose" to="/initialpose"/>
  </node>
  <node name="voxel_grid_2_point_cloud" pkg="costmap_2d" type="costmap_2d_cloud">
    <remap from="voxel_grid" to="/move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/voxel_grid"/>
    <remap from="voxel_marked_cloud" to="/move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/marked_cloud"/>
    <remap from="voxel_unknown_cloud" to="/move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/unknown_cloud"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

Voxel clouds are of 'PointCloud' type (not PointCloud2).

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-09-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8